# LINQ, EF Core : pull record from one list where it exist in other list

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, .net-5

I am working on a .NET 5 with Entity Framework Core application.

I have two lists:

1. List of strongly typed class data `creditCallRecords`
2. List of ids only in format `List<string>`

I need to pull only those records from `creditCallRecords` where the id is contained in that second `List<string>`.

I have tried to use the following LINQ code, but I'm getting errors:

```
(from csvRecord in creditCallRecords
 where csvRecord.CardEaseReference.Contains(recordReferencesToProcess)
 select csvRecord);
```

Error

> Cannot convert system.collection.Generic.List to Char

Comment: I suppose `CardEaseReference` is a string. Am I right?

Comment: Please add some more code to show the types of `csvRecord.CardEaseReference` and `recordReferencesToProcess`

Comment: correct it is string

Comment: @Toxic: what is in `recordReferencesToProcess` is it list of string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You wrote `where` clause in wrong direction.
Try

```
 where recordReferencesToProcess.Contains(csvRecord.CardEaseReference)
```

as `recordReferencesToProcess` is `List<string>` and it should contains `csvRecord.CardEaseReference`. In other way string from `csvRecord.CardEaseReference` is converted into `char[]` that causing an error